# Jquery ui timepicker wont fire

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, timepicker

I'm a javascript newby, and particularly jquery, and I am having trouble getting a datetimepicker to fire.
I am sure I am making a basic mistake but I can't for the life of me figure it out.
I am expecting the timepicker to fire when I click into it.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
(I'm using this timepicker -http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#rest_examples)

**External stylesheets and javascript files** - may or may not be relevant

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1/bi/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1/bi/assets/bootstrap/css/custom_bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://127.0.0.1/bi/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://127.0.0.1/bi/assets/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/bi/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/bi/assets/jquery_validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/bi/assets/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
```

**HTML** - relevant markup

```
<form class="well form" method="post" id="checkin">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="basic_example_1" id="basic_example_1" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="reset" class="btn">Clear</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="checkin" value="submit">Checkin</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript before `</body>`** - relevant javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please post simplified code examples. Yours is like... 90% irrelevant clutter.

Comment: maybe - but I am worried that something is conflicting with something else?

Comment: Also: are there any errors in the Javascript console? Did you verify using the debugger that your code actually gets called?

Comment: I didnt get any errors in the javascript console - thats why I am posting here

Comment: That's kind of the point of the exercise. You're supposed to test your simplified example. If the problem disappears, you know it was caused by something you removed.

Comment: I put a break in firebug and it got called. But only when it loaded - not when I clicked on the inputbox

Comment: I simplified the code but still couldnt get it to work by removing things.

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YKdm/) to make bug hunting a little easier. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hasDatepicker is added by jQuery UI, adding it yourself causes problems. Presumably, because it thinks it has already added a datepicker and won't add a second to the same element.

```
<input type="text" name="basic_example_1" id="basic_example_1" value="" />
```

Comment: My god - well done. Thats the actual code I got from the site.

Comment: Tell us why, Mr Copperfield?

Comment: Umm - are there any tools I could have used to diagnose this issue?

Comment: This particular issue was tricky, because there were no error messages. I created a fiddle and stripped away complexity until it worked. For instance, once I realized Datetimepicker was based on Datepicker (and Datepicker is a prereq) I modified the fiddle to attach a simple Datepicker to the field. That failed, so I needed to get that working before Datetimepicker would stand a chance.

Comment: Thankyou soo much. I'll use that technique in future!